# How would one access this from the Class inside a function in an object using TypeScript / Angular2

Tags: function, object, typescript, reference, this

In my angular2 project I have a DataService class.
I want to have a DataService.await.get() and DataService.await.put() but I'm having trouble getting the correct 'this' inside those methods.

This is what I have now:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  public await = {
    get(req): Observable<any> {
      return this.getIt(req); // I need 'this' to be the DataService
    },

    put(req, data): boolean {
      return this.putIt(req, data); // I need 'this' to be the DataService
  }

  constructor() {}

  private getIt(req: string): Observable<any> {
    return new ReplaySubject(1).AsObservable();
  }

  private putIt(req: string, data: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have seen some examples using arrow functions for functions within functions, but not for functions within an object...
How do I get 'this' to be a reference to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using arrow after all, appearantly all this time I was trying with get= instead of get:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  public await = {
    get: (req): Observable<any> => {
      return this.getIt(req); // I need 'this' to be the DataService
    },

    put: (req, data): boolean => {
      return this.putIt(req, data); // I need 'this' to be the DataService
  }

  constructor() {}

  private getIt(req: string): Observable<any> {
    return new ReplaySubject(1).AsObservable();
  }

  private putIt(req: string, data: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your property to a function that returns an object and use a little trick like this:

```
public await() {
    let that = this;

    return {

        get(req): Observable<any> {
            return that.getIt(req);
        },

        put(req, data): boolean {
            return that.putIt(req, data);
        }
    };
}
```

or you could initialize the await property in the constructor:

```
await: { get(req): Observable<any>, put(req, data): boolean };

constructor() {
    let that = this;
    this.await = {
        get(req): Observable<any> {
            return that.getIt(req);
        },

        put(req, data): boolean {
            return that.putIt(req, data);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: but then i would have to access it through DataService.await().get(), which i wanted to avoid....

Comment: ok, that would also work. Based on your first answer I made that function private _await, and then: public await = this._await();